# How to display instant preview without exporting FFmpeg video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-editing, ios

I am using FFMPEG to generate video from images but the problem is that I can only show the preview of the video after executing FFMPEG command and it’s takes time to generate output.

On terminal I can get instant preview of video using FFPLAY. But, how to do that same thing in iOS.

Comment: iOS questions are off-topic for this site unless the question is related to things directly interfacing between iOS devices and computers. Are you sure you don't mean macOS?

Comment: No i'm trying to just make app like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vido.particle.ly.lyrical.status.maker&hl=en_IN&gl=US in iOS. i want to that functionality which is in this app. So, please help me if you can some useful information about it in swift or ios